# Why is a TMVar populated in a function with putTMVar not visible from the calling function?

Tags: haskell, stm

In the following code I am sending a record with an `IO (TMVar o)` off to get populated in a function then reading
what I believe should be the same `TMVar` when the function returns. The problem is when I read it back it's empty and the application just blocks.

Why is this happening?

The Hook is intialised as follows:

```
hook = Hook { 
  -- other props
  hookResult = newEmptyTMVarIO,
 }
```

later in the ap:

```
executeHook :: (Text -> IO ()) -> Node i o -> IO ()
executeHook db =
  \case
    Fixture {} -> pure ()
    Hook
      { hookParent,
        hookStatus,
        hook,
        hookResult, -- IO (TMVar o)
        hookChildren
      } -> do
        input <- db "CALL PARENT LOCK EXECUTE HOOK" >> lockExecuteHook db hookParent
        result <- hook input
        hr <- hookResult
        mtb <- atomically $ isEmptyTMVar hr
        db $ "HOOK RESULT PUT EMPTY BEFORE: " <> txt mtb 
        atomically $ putTMVar hr result -- writes hook result to the TMVar
        mt <- atomically $ isEmptyTMVar hr
        db $ "HOOK RESULT PUT EMPTY AFTER: " <> txt mt 

lockExecuteHook :: (Text -> IO ()) -> Either o (Node i o) -> IO o
lockExecuteHook db parent =
  eitherf
    parent
    (\o -> db "NO PARENT HOOK RETURNING VALUE" >> pure o)
    ( \case
        Fixture {} -> pure ()
        hk@Hook
          { hookParent,
            hookStatus,
            hookResult, -- IO (TMVar o)
            hook,
            hookChildren,
            hookRelease
          } -> do
            bs <- hookStatus
            wantLaunch <- atomically $ tryLock db bs
            db $ "HOOK LOCK >>> " <> txt wantLaunch
            when
              wantLaunch
              $ executeHook db hk --  this writes hook result to the TMVar
            hr <- hookResult
            mt <- atomically $ isEmptyTMVar hr
            db $ "READING HOOK !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! EMPTY: " <> txt mt
            r <- atomically $ readTMVar hr
            db "RETURNING FROM LOCK EXECUTE HOOK " >> pure r
    )
```

Debug (db) output

```
CALL PARENT LOCK EXECUTE HOOK
HOOK LOCK >>> True
HOOK RESULT PUT EMPTY BEFORE: True
HOOK RESULT PUT EMPTY AFTER: False
READING HOOK !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! EMPTY: True
```

Comment: It seems you're creating a new `TMVar` every time. How does `hookResult` look?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I added the record field initialisation code to the question and with a bit of further experimentation I have proven you are right. The way I have done it `hookResult` is a thunk not a single `TMVar`. I think I need to create my `Hook` record inside IO and pass around a `TMVar o` as the value of `hookResult` not an `IO (TMVar o)`

Comment: I think your heart is in the right place, but "thunk" is not the right name for why this went wrong. Even if it were fully evaluated you would observe this behavior; the problem is that it's still an `IO` action, not the result of executing that action. Evaluation -- turning a thunk into a value -- and execution -- performing the effects described by an `IO` value -- are separate concepts.

Comment: @JohnWalker Indeed, you need to make the field to be a plain `TMVar o`, and initialize that properly. Right now, you are passing around  `hookResult = newEmptyTVarIO` as an action, and every time you run `hr <- hookResult` you are effectively running `hr <- newEmptyTVarIO` creating a new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the above comments by @FyodorSoikin, @DanielWagner and @chi, the reason this was not working as expected is that `hookResult` was not initialised correctly.

Setting the record field to an `IO (TMVar a)` will result in a new `TMVar a` every time `hookResult` is read, similar problem would occur if the field was set to an `STM (TMVar a)` using `newTMVar`. To make this work `hookResult` needs to be set to a `TMVar a` from within the IO or STM context.

```
eg :: IO (Hook a)
eg = do
       v <- newEmptyTMVarIO
       pure $ Hook { 
         -- other props
         hookResult = v,
       }
```